# MongoDB Updating multiple records based on the Nth value in an array using the C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Suppose I have the following documents inside a collection:

```
[{ id:1, items: [1, 4, 1], flag:false},
{ id:2, items: [3, 1, 3], flag:false },
{ id:3, items: [2, 4, 6], flag:false },
{ id:4, items: [8, 7, 2], flag:false }]
```

I am required to Set `flag` to `true` if `items[1] == 4`.
So, the state of the collection after the update would be:

```
{ id:1, items: [1, 4, 1], flag:true},
{ id:2, items: [3, 1, 3], flag:false },
{ id:3, items: [2, 4, 6], flag:true},
{ id:4, items: [8, 7, 2], flag:false }
```

How do I do this using the `C#` driver?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the native mongodb query - `db.t.update({"items.1":4},{$set:{flag:true}},{"multi":true})`, if you could post what you have tried in C#, it would be easy to fix your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query to do the update via mongo shell

```
db.test.update({'items.1' : 4}, { $set :  { flag : true}}, {multi : true})
```

The C# code would be:

```
var url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var client = new MongoClient(url);
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection("test");

var query = Query.EQ("items.1", 4);
var update = Update.Set("flag", true);

collection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the second version of MongoDB.Driver (2.0.0-beta2) you can do this:

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");

await collection.UpdateManyAsync(
    filter => filter.Items[1] == 4,
    update => update.Set(ent => ent.Flag, true));
```

Assuming you have **Entity** class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}
```